# What's the difference between list and List in Python 3.8

Tags: python, list, python-3.8

For type annotations, in `Python 3.8` versions and earlier, it was explicitly required to import `List` as a valid type. So, we had to do something like `from typing import List`.

Why did we have to create a new type `List` and not use the built-in `list` type in pre `Python 3.9`?

Comment: Because `list` could not be parameterized, because `list[whatever]` would throw an error. It was decided that having special types for annotation would be messy, so in 3.9 now the built-in types support parameterization.

Answer (score 8):

`list` is the builtin `list` class. You can directly annotate with that.

`typing.List` is the type hint for lists, *which can be subscripted*, e.g.:

```
foo: List[str] = []
```

This allows more fine-grained type hinting than `list` does, since you can annotate what types are expected within the list.

[Since Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) the builtin `list` also supports subscriptions, which it didn't before.

Comment: How did they make list subscriptable in Python 3.9?

Comment: Magic! … And something called [PEP585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

Answer (score 2):

typing.List isn't a `list` - its a generic. You CAN use `list` in your typing, but you can be more specific using `List`.  For example.

```
from typing import List


def unspecific_func(arg: list):
  return ', '.join(arg)

def specific_func(arg: List[str]):
  return ', '.join(arg)
```

If you tried to do `unspecific_func([1, 3, 5])` your type hints would not be enough to tell you that this is an error. But doing `List[str]` as the type hint is not only saying it should be a list, but the members of that list should all be strings!